# Как передать значение переменной в корзину Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

У меня есть переменная $per, которая хранит в себе код заказа (см. скрин).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я хочу выводить это значение в корзине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как его сохранить и вывести?

Я пробовал вот так, но как мне объяснили, тут нужен AJAX обработчик. И оно выводит ошибку.

```
<?php


$product_id = 0;
$quantity = 1;
$variation_id = 0;
$variation = [];
$attribures = [];
$per = 'Код заказа'; 
$cart_item_data = [ 
   'new_per' => $per,
];



$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $attribures, $cart_item_data ); 
}
```

Comment: Выводит ошибку так как `$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart()` принимает 5 параметров согласно [документации](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Cart::add_to_cart), Вы передаете 6-ть.

Comment: Один надо убрать?

Comment: По идее нужно убрать `$attribures` так как изначально под этим скорее всего и подразумевалось `$cart_item_data`, просто там откуда Вы копировали/взяли код, переменная называлась иначе. Это решит проблему с ошибкой, но не решит проблему с выводом в корзине, так как там фиксированное количество колонок и добавление этого атрибута не значит что там появится новая колонка в таблице.

Comment: С выводом в корзине разберусь, но теперь вопрос - где этот код, что написан выше, вставить. У меня он в functions.php  в хуке woocommerce_single_product_summary, и я думаю, это неверно. @Simon

Comment: [Add Custom Cart Item Data in WooCommerce](https://iconicwp.com/blog/add-custom-cart-item-data-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 0):

Добавить input type="hidden" value="$per"
в content-single-product.php куда то внутри формы add-to-cart.

это в новый плагин или function.php
/**

- @param array $cart_item_data
- @param int   $product_id
- @param int   $variation_id
- 
- @return array
  */
  function iconic_add_engraving_text_to_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
  $per = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'per' );

  $cart_item_data['per'] = $per;

  return $cart_item_data;
  }

ну и в корзине:
выводим

Наверное костыль, но я так делал с вариативными товарами.